# Escaping backlash and double quotes inside a sed expression (surrounded by double quotes)

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, quoting, text-formatting

```
$ echo 'output: " ' | sed "s/\"/\"/"
output: "

$ echo 'output: " ' | sed "s/\"/\\\"/"
output: "

$ echo 'output: " ' | sed "s/\"/\\\\\"/"
output: \"
```

I want to understand what is happening in the first and second example.
What I understand is, since I am using double quotes for the `sed` expression, `\"` is interpreded as `"` and `\\` is interpreted as `\`.
If so then why is my second output comming out to be `"` instead of `\"`?

I know I could have used single quotes in `sed` as `'s/"/\"/'` and it *doesn't* works as inteded and replaces `"` with `"`.

I am really curious why this behaviour is observed for double quotes.

- GNU bash, version 5.1.4(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
- sed (GNU sed) 4.8

Comment: You say `'s/"/\"/'` works? It shouldn't. You would need `\\"` in the replacement text.

Comment: oh yes thats a mistake, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [shell specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_03):

> **2.2.3 Double-Quotes**
>
> Enclosing characters in double-quotes ( "" ) shall preserve the literal value of all characters within the double-quotes, with the exception of the characters backquote, dollar-sign, and backslash, as follows:
>
> (...)
>
> The backslash shall retain its special meaning as an escape character only when followed by one of the following characters when considered special:
> $   `   "   \   <newline>

Therefore,

| Case | Before shell (what you see) | After shell (what Sed gets) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `"s/\"/\"/"` | `s/"/"/` |
| 2 | `"s/\"/\\\"/"` | `s/"/\"/` |
| 3 | `"s/\"/\\\\\"/"` | `s/"/\\"/` |

In [Sed's specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_03), `s` command:

> The meaning of an unescaped backslash immediately followed by any character other than '&',
> backslash, a digit, newline, or the delimiter character used for this command, is unspecified.

So in case 2 the output is unspecified (i.e., Sed implementations are free
to interpret such cases as they like). GNU Sed took that freedom to offer
several special characters, among which `\r` for carriage return, `\n` for newline, etc.
(see [the complete list in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Escapes.html)). `\"` is not one of them and it chooses to
simply remove the backslash. As a result, case 2 becomes equivalent to case 1 in GNU Sed.