# sed command to replace $Date$ with $Date: 2021-01-06

Tags: sed

I need to use a `sed` command to search a text file and replace `$Date$` with:  `$Date: 2021-01-06... $`
where `...` is the text for the date.

I have a `sed` command that will search for `Date` and replace it with  `Date:  2021-01-06...`:

```
sed "s/Date/Date $(date)/"
```

but I can't get a `sed` command to work to replace `$Date$`.

Also, I was able to get a `sed` command to replace `$Date`   using `sed "s/\$Date/\$Date $(date)/"`  but I can't figure out the syntax to search and replace `$Date$`.

I tried:

```
sed "s/\$Date\$/\$Date $(date) \$/"
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Very similar question asked just yesterday: [Escaping backlash and double quotes inside a sed expression (surrounded by double quotes)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/627824)

Comment: The question title does not match the equirement.The trailing $ should be dropped from the title meaning whereas in the requirements it is shown as retained.

Answer (score 13):

> I tried: `sed "s/\$Date\$/\$Date $(date) \$/"` but it does not work.

Because `\$` in double-quotes only tells the shell not to interpret (expand) `$`, but then there's `sed`. It gets `s/$Date$/$Date … $/` (where `…` denotes what `$(date)` expanded to) and interprets the second `$` as an anchor matching the end of the line. In `s/regexp/replacement/` `$` is interpreted as the anchor only at the end of `regexp`. So you need to escape this particular `$` also for `sed`, i.e. you need `sed` to literally get `\$`. This can be done with:

```
sed "s/\$Date\\$/\$Date $(date) \$/"
```

or

```
sed "s/\$Date\\\$/\$Date $(date) \$/"
```

It works with two or three backslashes because double-quoted `$` before `/` does not need to (but may) be escaped, and to get `\` you need `\\` in double-quotes. This is kinda complicated, therefore consider single-quoting all fragments that don't need to be double-quoted:

```
sed 's/$Date\$/$Date '"$(date)"' $/'
```

Here all `$` characters that should get to `sed` are single-quoted; and the only `\` that should get to `sed` is also single-quoted.

Answer (score 3):

To cut down on the backslashes we shall use the `GNU sed` with its extended regex mode `-E` turned ON. Plus, we shall use the back referencing brackets to further cut down on the rhs of the s/// command.
Plus, we utilize the dollar inside a character class `[...]`  gets treated as a literal.

```
sed -Ee "s/([\$]Date)([\$])/\1 $(date) \2/"
```

---

Or, Posixly we can do as shown:

```
sed -e '/\($Date\)\$/ '"s//\1 $(date) \$/"
```